# VW34 Could not Compile ./bootstrap

Tags: bootstrapping

./bootstrap 
automake version 1.7 or newer required
./configure
No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

VW34's bootstrap doesn't take into account 2 digit sub versions.  1.10 or 1.11 both show up as 1.1.  The best way to make it work is to edit the bootstrap file and put # before both the "exit 1" lines.